# Convert JObject having template JSON data to XAML

Tags: json, xaml, xamarin

I have a template JSON String in JSONTemplate.json file in following format:

```
{"components":[{"clearOnHide":false,"key":"Clientaccount","input":false,"title":"Clientaccount","theme":"default","tableView":false,"components":[{"clearOnHide":false,"label":"Columns","input":false,"tableView":false,"key":"clientaccount Columns","columns":[{"components":[{"type":"textfield","input":true,"tableView":true,"inputType":"text","inputMask":"","label":"bankaccountnumber","key":"bankaccountnumber","placeholder":"Enter bankaccountnumber","prefix":"","suffix":"","multiple":false,"defaultValue":"","protected":false,"unique":false,"persistent":true,"validate":{"required":"true","pattern":"","custom":"","customPrivate":false},"conditional":{"show":"","when":null,"eq":""}}],"width":3,"offset":0,"push":0,"pull":0},{"components":[{"type":"textfield","input":true,"tableView":true,"inputType":"text","inputMask":"","label":"bankname","key":"bankname","placeholder":"Enter bankname","prefix":"","suffix":"","multiple":false,"defaultValue":"","protected":false,"unique":false,"persistent":true,"validate":{"required":"true","pattern":"","custom":"","customPrivate":false},"conditional":{"show":"","when":null,"eq":""}}],"width":3,"offset":0,"push":0,"pull":0},{"components":[{"type":"textfield","input":true,"tableView":true,"inputType":"text","inputMask":"","label":"casenumber","key":"casenumber","placeholder":"Enter casenumber","prefix":"","suffix":"","multiple":false,"defaultValue":"","protected":false,"unique":false,"persistent":true,"validate":{"required":"true","pattern":"","custom":"","customPrivate":false},"conditional":{"show":"","when":null,"eq":""}}],"width":3,"offset":0,"push":0,"pull":0},{"components":[{"type":"textfield","input":true,"tableView":true,"inputType":"text","inputMask":"","label":"clientaccountno","key":"clientaccountno","placeholder":"Enter clientaccountno","prefix":"","suffix":"","multiple":false,"defaultValue":"","protected":false,"unique":false,"persistent":true,"validate":{"required":"true","pattern":"","custom":"","customPrivate":false},"conditional":{"show":"","when":null,"eq":""}}],"width":3,"offset":0,"push":0,"pull":0}],"type":"columns","hideLabel":true,"tags":[],"conditional":{"show":"","when":null,"eq":""},"properties":{}}],"type":"panel","breadcrumb":"default","tags":[],"conditional":{"show":"","when":null,"eq":""},"properties":{},"hideLabel":false,"isNew":false},{"type":"button","theme":"primary","disableOnInvalid":true,"action":"submit","block":false,"rightIcon":"","leftIcon":"","size":"md","key":"submit","tableView":false,"label":"Submit","input":true,"$$hashKey":"object:22","autofocus":false,"customClass":"text-right","event":"onFormSumit"}]}
```

I have deserialized the JSON string to JObject as follows:

```
        JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\JSONTemplate.json"));

        // read JSON directly from a file
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"D:\JSONTemplate.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
           
        }
```

I want to get this converted to XAML so that it can be used in Xamarin mobile application.
I have searched for similar solutions but could not find much.

Comment: there is no magic method that will convert this to XAML for you.  You will need to write code to do that

Comment: Any guidance as to how to proceed with creating XAML manually will be helpful as I am new to Xamarin.

Comment: Hi, if you could deserialize the json data, then can refer to [From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) to show it in View(`Xaml`).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is complex, so you should analyze it first and create a structure or class that fits your data. Here is my example;
DataModel

```
public class MyData
{
   public IList<component> components;
}

public class Component
{
   public bool clearOnHide;
   public string key;
   public bool input;
   public string title;
   public string theme;
   public IList<Component> components; // Components in the element
   ...
}
```

And you can deserialize a string typed json using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method.

```
string jsonstring = "{'components':[{'clearOnHide':false,'key':'Clientaccount','input':false,'title':'Clientaccount','theme':'default','tableView':false,'components':[{'clearOnHide':false,'label':'Columns','input':false,'tableView':false,'key':'clientaccount Columns','columns':[{'components':[{'type':'textfield','input':true,'tableView':true,'inputType':'text','inputMask':'','label':'bankaccountnumber','key':'bankaccountnumber','placeholder':'Enter bankaccountnumber','prefix':'','suffix':'','multiple':false,'defaultValue':'','protected':false,'unique':false,'persistent':true,'validate':{'required':'true','pattern':'','custom':'','customPrivate':false},'conditional':{'show':'','when':null,'eq':''}}],'width':3,'offset':0,'push':0,'pull':0},{'components':[{'type':'textfield','input':true,'tableView':true,'inputType':'text','inputMask':'','label':'bankname','key':'bankname','placeholder':'Enter bankname','prefix':'','suffix':'','multiple':false,'defaultValue':'','protected':false,'unique':false,'persistent':true,'validate':{'required':'true','pattern':'','custom':'','customPrivate':false},'conditional':{'show':'','when':null,'eq':''}}],'width':3,'offset':0,'push':0,'pull':0},{'components':[{'type':'textfield','input':true,'tableView':true,'inputType':'text','inputMask':'','label':'casenumber','key':'casenumber','placeholder':'Enter casenumber','prefix':'','suffix':'','multiple':false,'defaultValue':'','protected':false,'unique':false,'persistent':true,'validate':{'required':'true','pattern':'','custom':'','customPrivate':false},'conditional':{'show':'','when':null,'eq':''}}],'width':3,'offset':0,'push':0,'pull':0},{'components':[{'type':'textfield','input':true,'tableView':true,'inputType':'text','inputMask':'','label':'clientaccountno','key':'clientaccountno','placeholder':'Enter clientaccountno','prefix':'','suffix':'','multiple':false,'defaultValue':'','protected':false,'unique':false,'persistent':true,'validate':{'required':'true','pattern':'','custom':'','customPrivate':false},'conditional':{'show':'','when':null,'eq':''}}],'width':3,'offset':0,'push':0,'pull':0}],'type':'columns','hideLabel':true,'tags':[],'conditional':{'show':'','when':null,'eq':''},'properties':{}}],'type':'panel','breadcrumb':'default','tags':[],'conditional':{'show':'','when':null,'eq':''},'properties':{},'hideLabel':false,'isNew':false},{'type':'button','theme':'primary','disableOnInvalid':true,'action':'submit','block':false,'rightIcon':'','leftIcon':'','size':'md','key':'submit','tableView':false,'label':'Submit','input':true,'$$hashKey':'object:22','autofocus':false,'customClass':'text-right','event':'onFormSumit'}]}";

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(jsonstring);
```

After deserializing the object, you can use the object like this:

```
foreach(Component comp in root.components)
{
   Console.WriteLine(comp.title);
   if(comp.components != null)
   {
      foreach(Compoent subcomp in comp.components){
         Console.WriteLine(subcomp.title);
      }
   }
}
```

You need to add the Newtonsoft.Json package in your project to use the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method.

Comment: After deserializing the object, how can it be converted to XAML? Any code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: I have created a control and have added to ContentPage.Content in C#. Now can we retrieve XAML complete UI code from the Content? I have to save this Xamarin form ui code in database. Any help?

Comment: @TechEnthusiast Can you share your code here?